# Is there any way to free the executable and it's dependencies after using it with Exec in NSIS

Tags: nsis

To free the DLL we are using "?u" like as shown below when we are Calling the DLL.

```
System::Call "Launch.dll::IsDriverPresent() i.r0 ?u"
```

Similarly Is there any way to free or unload the exe and it's dependencies after it used?

Because sometimes after uninstallation in the installed directory executable and its dependencies are still present.

Below is the line we are using to call Exec:

```
Exec '"$INSTDIR\ValidateDriver.exe" ON'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot unload a .EXE. A .EXE will be locked until its final thread ends and all handles to all threads and the process itself have been closed.

If you Kill/Terminate the process and it is still locked then most likely there is some Anti-Virus software still holding a lock on the file.

You can call `Delete` and `Sleep` in a loop and after 10 seconds or so of retrying you might have to just give up or display a MessageBox to the user.

Comment: I am using WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" to create uninstall.exe in the Installed directory.
Can I use the below line in Section "Uninstall" to uninstall and wait until it deletes the exes and dlls?

ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"'

And also can i use the below lines in "Uninstall" section to delete and wait?

delete "Launch.dll"
sleep 3000

Comment: You cannot call uninstall.exe in a uninstall section. You can delete other files.